# Sharing data between requests to the same view in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a simple view in django

```
class SimpleView(View):   
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):   
        c = C()
        c.m()

class C:
    def m(self):
        x = # get from an external server if not set
```

I would like to share `x` across different requests to `SimpleView`

For example, let's consider the following scenario:

1. Someone#1 requests `get` to `SimpleView`. `x` is not set up, so it will be fetched from an external server.
2. Someone#2 requests `get` to `SimpleView`. `x` is set up, so it won't be fetched from an external server.

I know that that piece of code doesn't do it. I know what is a global variable. But, I don't know how to **share data between different requests**. I don't want to use a database to store it (because of the optimization)- the value `x` don't have to be persistent.

Please note that it will be great if that method to sharing something be a thread-safe (it is not neccessary, I deal with it).

How to do it?

(django 1.6)

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not need to store the data permanently, you should use the [session store](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/) for this.

Normally the session engine is configured to use the database; it is possible to use other backends, but there is rarely any good reason to do so.

(Note also, you should upgrade your version of Django; 1.6 is old, unsupported, and probably insecure.)

Comment: Thanks! :), I have two questions more:
From my basic understanding of `session` it is not shared by a different client, maybe I misunderstand session here, do I?

Comment: What's about another solution?

Comment: Why do you want to share the value between clients?

Comment: because `x` is common for every request. Fetching every time is too expensive.